# Where to put the dakuten and handakuten?

Tags: katakana, hiragana

When writing hiragana and katakana, does the position of the dakuten and handakuten matter? I know it should always be placed after the character but there also some questions like these:

What should the space between the dakuten and character?

Should the dakuten be placed on the same level as the very top of the character? Or could it exceed than the very top of the character?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters. They are placed around the top-right corner, mostly.

がぎぐげご

ざじずぜぞ

だぢづでど

ばびぶべぼ

ぱぴぷぺぽ

で seems to be the odd one out. Doesn't have to be perfect, as long as it's there.

Comment: Also, the dakuten is inside the く in ぐ

Comment: Please see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69041/5010).