# Is there a reason why the 濁点【だくてん】（ ﾞ）are placed below the stroke at ぐ and で as opposed to the other hiragana characters?

Tags: punctuation, calligraphy

Most of the 平仮名【ひらがな】 characters have the 濁点【だくてん】 above the stroke but there are two cases where it is placed below the stroke:

> がぎげござじずぜぞだぢづどばびぶべぼ
>
> ぐで

Why?

Comment: I suspect this has less to do with handwriting and more to do with pixel allotment for characters in a font, but not sure.

Comment: For what it's worth, in whatever font is the default on my iPad, ご looks like it belongs with ぐ and で.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The position of a dakuten is not as strict as you think. It has to be placed near the top right corner, but it may be moved or rotated according to the font designer's choice. Here are some examples of voiced hiragana rendered with various fonts installed on my PC:

[image]

When you practice handwriting, please use shapes of a [教科書体](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25345/5010) font (the blue one above).